# Grid View as demoed in iPad

Tags: iphone, layout, ipad

I'm trying to develop a grid-like application for the iPad. Has anyone seen a control that displays info in a grid? In the demos they use a grid-like layout in both the iBooks store and the pictures application.

Specifically in pictures, they are displaying a dynamic list of data in a grid.

I can work around it, of course, but I'd rather use a control if one exists. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The people who know what controls are or or not in the 3.2 iPhone dev tools have all committed to Apple NDA so we can't tell you.

Steve is always watching.

If you have signed the NDA you should go to the Apple boards and ask.

You can however, make a gird like display very simply with the standard UITableview. Just have a tableviewcell subclass that displays columns. It took me about an hour to reproduce the photo picker display using that method.

Comment: Thanks, that's probably the route I'll go. However, the 3.2 SDK is freely available. They have plenty of documentation on the new controls. I just couldn't find anything like a grid.

Comment: @Sean, the 3.2 Beta SDK is not freely available. It is available at no cost to iPhone Developer Program Members only and it is considered Apple Confidential Information.

Comment: Huh.. Yeah, I meant "if you are already an iphone developer", but I had no idea it was under NDA. I don't remember signing / agreeing to a new one when I downloaded it, but I may have just flown past it. Thanks

Comment: No problem. I think we all fly past that bit of information without really thinking about what we are agreeing too (the evil of EULAs and such). Now, I just assume that everything beta for Apple is NDA. :)

Comment: You do need to be careful with the NDAs. Apple takes them very seriously. I worked at Apple for 9 years and I saw people burn their relationship with Apple by not taking them seriously. I wasn't kidding about "Steve is always watching". Jobs is noted for taking sudden interest in seemingly trivial aspects of the company.

Comment: So let's see, "It took me about an hour to reproduce the photo picker display using that method"... so that's one TechZen hour. Who knows what that translates to for the OP: probably 8-10 hours?

Comment: @Yar-- That's true. Skill does matter. My spouse is a great cook and can whip out dishes in minutes that would take me hours. However, the actual logic of creating the grid is not that difficult.

Answer (score 8):

DTGridView:

http://www.danieltull.co.uk/blog/2009/10/28/dtgridview/

Answer (score 6):

You should try [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView) it does what you need.
Here are few screens of apps that use this library:
[image: app1] [image: app2]

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you will have to create your own. People have been writing Home Screen compatible views though, so you might want to search for open source projects with that functionality.